# Перенос строки в display: table-cell

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы элементы списка поместились в фиксированную ширину списка. При этом не поместившиеся элементы переносились на новую строку.

К примеру, должно получиться по 3 элемента на каждую строку.

http://jsfiddle.net/VAva2/

Пробую использовать для списка display: table, для элементов списка display: table-cell, но они не переносятся, а ширина элементов подстраивается под размеры всего списка. 
Какое должно быть решение?

Comment: li {display:inline-block} ?  
почему вы кстати не используете непосредственно таблицу?  
браузер не будет для вас генерить элемент с display:table-row, все ваши li(с display:table-cell) будут всегда лежать на одной строке.

Comment: Потому что должен быть именно список. 
Нужно переместить остальные 3 блока вниз под верхние.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что структура таблицы состоит из жесткой иерархии: блок таблицы (основа **table**), потом идут строки (**tr**), а в строках колонки (**td**).

**То-бишь!** Все ваши элементы списка (псевдо колонки “*display: table-cell;*”) растягиваются на стопроцентную высоту – единственной строки. И новая строка, сама-по-себе, не создастся никогда.

Вот вам мой вариант реализации вашего списка:
http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/ysj3k/

Учтите! «inline-block» - не поддерживается старыми браузерами, типа ИЕ7 и ниже. Но и это исправимо. Хотя, лично я, против поддержки старых браузеров!

Также, с бордерами много проблем, особенно при зуме.
Советую вам создать в элементах списка DIV-ы, и уже им задать бордеры.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Я уже нашла решение немного другим, но похожим способом. 
Хорошо, что ИЕ мне совсем не важен, да и бордеры были просто для визуального удобства.